# How to get currently visible index in RN flat list

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have a horizontal flat list where each item is `width:300`
All I am trying to do is to get index of currently visible item.

```
<FlatList 
            onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)} 
            horizontal={true}
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem...
```

Tried this:

```
handleScroll(event) {
    let index = Math.ceil(
      event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / 300
    );
```

And something like this:

```
handleScroll(event) {
  let contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
  let index = Math.floor(contentOffset.x / 300);
```

but nothing is accurate I always get one index up or one index down.
What am I doing wrong and how to get correct current index in flat list?
*For example I get to list item that is 8th in a list but I get index 9 or 10.*

[image]

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**UPD**. thanks to @ch271828n for pointing that onViewableItemsChanged shouldn`t be updated

You can use FlatList `onViewableItemsChanged` prop to get what you want.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
    console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
  }

  render () => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged }
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

`viewabilityConfig` can help you to make whatever you want with viewability settings. In code example `50` means that item is considered visible if it is visible for more than 50 percents.

Config stucture can be found [here](https://github.com/rexxars/react-native/blob/fc497b63a9abec53cd5c714349b8a7270c743a3b/Libraries/Experimental/ViewabilityHelper.js)

Comment: But how I can know which data to use. Because item is 300p wide and if it's in the middle I will see 20p  of left and right items, ok here I can get middle one. But if there are two items how to pick the next to get it's data.

Comment: This callback returns all three items as visible. Only fully gone items will be marked as not visible.

Comment: I updated the question with image. When I got two items visible like on image. I need to get only one item data (possibly the one that is more visible than another). Is it possible with this callback somehow?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you can experiment with values now and get what you really want

Comment: @RomanOsypov Thanks, works for me. But I want to know, is there any function I can call to get the `viewableItems`? As I think `onViewableItemsChanged` will be called multi times upon scrolling events. Hence want to be more efficient. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use throttle or debounce for the callback on this event.

Comment: In react native 0.54 says: **ExceptionsManager.js:65 Invariant Violation: Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported**

Comment: @S.HosseinAsadollahi I believe you should move arrow  function from FlatList props and provide in immutble manner.

Comment: <FlatList
  onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
  viewabilityConfig={{
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
  }}
/>

Comment: I tried this for hours on an Expo 37.0.3 project running in an Android simulator.  It won't fire at all.  `onScroll` fires fine, so it's something specific with `onViewableItemsChanged`, perhaps with Android or this version of Expo.

Comment: @Roman Osypov I am using functional component and used state to save index the code working with the console.log() but when itry to add the set state code it throw error as 'Error: Changing viewabilityConfig on the fly is not supported'

Comment: @S.HosseinAsadollahi Change the `onViewableItemsChanged` callback to `React.useRef`.

Answer (score 29):

With related to @fzyzcjy's and @Roman's answers. In react, 16.8+ you can use `useCallback` to handle the `changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported` error.

```js
    function MyComponent(props) {
        const _onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
            console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
            console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
        }, []);
    
        const _viewabilityConfig = {
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
        }
    
        return <FlatList
                onViewableItemsChanged={_onViewableItemsChanged}
                viewabilityConfig={_viewabilityConfig}
                {...props}
            />;
    }
```

Comment: _viewabilityConfig should be created with useMemo or put it outside function MyComponent() in module scope

Comment: Can I ask why ?

Comment: Eventually used this to do some stuff based on a viewable item on screen, thanks

Answer (score 18):

Many thanks to the most-voted answer :) However, it does not work when I try it, raising an error saying that `changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported`. After some search, I find the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17408). Here is the full code that can run without error. The key point is that the two configs should be put as **class properties** instead of inside the render() function.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {  
  _onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
    console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
  };

  _viewabilityConfig = {
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
          onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
          viewabilityConfig={this._viewabilityConfig}
          {...this.props}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm running into this problem as well, but I'm using a functional component, not a class. Do you have any ideas to help me?

Comment: hmm maybe `useCallback`? I have not written React for years...

Comment: @Josiah Did you got the answer ?

Comment: A bit late to the party, but here is the link to the issue on Github where a contributor proposed a solution for functional component. Hopefully it will help somebody

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30171#issuecomment-711154425

Answer (score 10):

```
this.handleScroll = (event) => {
  let yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
  let contentHeight = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height
  let value = yOffset / contentHeight
}

<FlatList onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

Get the round-off value to calculate the page-number/index.

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: Good suggestion. On Android, onViewableItemsChanged sometimes reports cached items as visible items. So use handleScroll or onMomentumScrollEnd with this suggested calculation is much better.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, I guess, you might ignore the `padding` or `margin` of items. The `contentOffsetX` or `contentOffsetY` should be `firstViewableItemIndex` * (`itemWidth` + `item padding or margin`).

[image]

As other answers, `onViewableItemsChanged` would be a better choice to meet your requirement. I wrote an article about how to use it and how it is implemented. 
https://suelan.github.io/2020/01/21/onViewableItemsChanged/

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but for me was different with functional components...

If you are using functional component do it like:

```
  const onScroll = useCallback((event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    const slideSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
    const index = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / slideSize;
    const roundIndex = Math.round(index);
    console.log("roundIndex:", roundIndex);
  }, []);
```

Then on your FlatList

```
<FlatList
      data={[2, 3]}
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      onScroll={onScroll}
    />
```

Comment: The roundIndex is always 0 in this case @manuel

Answer (score 2):

While `onViewableItemsChanged` works for some conditions, it gives the

```
Error: Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported
```

error when ever you try to set the state.

This issue is fixed by using `viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs` instead of `onViewableItemsChanged`.

```js
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const App = () => {
    // The name of the function must be onViewableItemsChanged.
    const onViewableItemsChanged = ({viewableItems}) => {
        console.log(viewableItems);
        // Your code here.
    };
    const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef([{onViewableItemsChanged}]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.root}>
            <FlatList
              data={data}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={
                  viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current
              }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Checkout this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30171#issuecomment-820833606) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

this will solve

> Invariant Violation: Changing viewabilityConfig on the fly is not
> supported

, and `type script` error on `viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs`.

```
const onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {

console.log(viewableItems)
};
     
const viewabilityConfig = { itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100 };

const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef([
{ viewabilityConfig, onViewableItemsChanged },
]);
                       
<FlatList
       
...
viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={
viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current
}
           
//viewabilityConfig={{ itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100,  }}<--------remove this 
       />
```

**typeScript:**

```
import {ViewToken} from "react-native";

const onViewableItemsChanged = ({viewableItems}: {viewableItems: ViewToken[]}) => {
...
```

Answer (score -3):

Kindly use class-based components. `onViewableItemsChanged()` method only works with classes otherwise it will give an error